# How to use ProgressBar Border from image and Progress Indicator in image's transparent area in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, progress-bar

I have a Picture (Track) Like this-

[image]

The White Portion you can see is actually transparent. I want to fill it with Color (Indicator) according to it's progress, like this-

[image]

But the problem is that, whenever I am setting the image (Track) in Blend the "Progress Color" (Indicator) actually covers up it's Border (Track) like this-

[image]

For ease, I have attached the code-

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">


        <ProgressBar Value="50" Height="50" Width="450" Foreground="Red" BorderThickness="10" Background="{x:Null}">
            <ProgressBar.BorderBrush>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="MOyml.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </ProgressBar.BorderBrush>          
        </ProgressBar>   
</Window>
```

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the appropriate tutorial to handle this operation

[Use shape in a progressbar](http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2009/11/24/wpf-controltemplates-creating-a-non-rectangular-progressbar.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the control template so the fill goes in the right place.

Comment: Can you please tell how to do in that case?